# iOS Autolayout Constraints animation breaks inner view position

Tags: ios, animation, uiwebview, autolayout

I am using Autolayout and contraints, I need to animate a view as if it came from a thumbnail to fullscreen. The view has one child, a webview which is attached to its four sides with constraints.

This is what I do:

```
- (void)animate {

trailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1
                                                             constant:_trailing];
leadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1
                                                            constant:_leading];
bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1
                                                           constant:_bottom];
topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.superview.superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1
                                                        constant:_top];

[self.superview.superview addConstraint:trailingConstraint];
[self.superview.superview addConstraint:leadingConstraint];
[self.superview.superview addConstraint:topConstraint];
[self.superview.superview addConstraint:bottomConstraint];

[self.superview.superview layoutIfNeeded];

self.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    self.closeButton.hidden = NO;
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    trailingConstraint.constant = 0;
    leadingConstraint.constant = 0;
    bottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    topConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.superview.superview layoutIfNeeded];
}                completion:nil];
```

}

I call that method after adding the view to the superview, and I call the opposite when I close the view

It works fine. But the inner view, a UIWebview does not resize together with the animation, it takes the final size before the animation starts, it flickers and becomes big (or small when closing) and then the animation starts on self and is self resizes correctly.

What could be wrong?

The webview does not have size constraints, it has position constraints, the same as self basically -> 0 for four sides to self and these constraints are not changed.

Comment: I tried the other way round and it would not work, it works this way.

Comment: My bad, I read the code too fast. Had the impressions that `constraintWithItem:` and `toItem:` where the same views.

Comment: Are you re-adding the constraints to the view each time you animate? You are supposed to install the constraints within `updateViewConstraints`, and then in `animate` only change the constant and call `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: I only add the constraints once, I create the view, add it, animate, close it, animate out and remove from super view.